# Download videos in php

Tags: php

i want to download mp4 videos using php.But following code not working.How can i download mp4 or other videos using php.

This is my code.

```
  header('Content-type: video/flv');  
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="video.flv"');  
  readfile('original.flv');
```

Comment: Put some of your code here. So we can answer it.

Comment: @Syed Noman : i used following code.

header('Content-type: video/flv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="video.flv"');
readfile('original.flv');

Answer (score 1):

try this,

HTML

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
   <source src="http://localhost/videos/mp4.php" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

mp4.php

```
$file = 'local_file';
$newfile = 'outFile';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($newfile));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn about File Transfer Protocol (FTP) in PHP

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_ftp.asp

Hope this helps. :)